# String compare function in x86 assembly - seg fault

Tags: function, assembly, x86, nasm, procedure

I'm trying to make an x86 function that accepts two strings as arguments and determines which is larger. The arguments are obtained through user input and I'm using NASM. However once I get this to work I'm just going to call my assembly function in a c program so this might just be giving myself more work than needed for testing. I'd really appreciate any help finding out why this code seg faults.

```
SECTION .data

greet:  db      "Type a word: "
greetL: equ     $-greet
bigprompt:   db "First is bigger"
bigpromptL: equ $-bigprompt
smallprompt:     db "Second is bigger"
smallpromptL:   equ $-smallprompt
sameprompt: db "They same: "
samepromptL:    equ $-sameprompt
LF: equ 10

SECTION .bss

first: resb 30
second: resb 30

SECTION .text

global  _start

_start:
    nop
    mov     eax, 4          ; ask for first word
    mov     ebx, 1          
    mov     ecx, greet      
    mov     edx, greetL     
    int     80H         

    mov     eax, 3          ; get first word
    mov     ebx, 0          
    mov     ecx, first      
    mov     edx, 30 
    int     80H             

    mov     eax, 4                  ; ask for second word
    mov     ebx, 1
    mov     ecx, greet
    mov     edx, greetL
    int         80H

    mov     eax, 3                  ; get second word
    mov     ebx, 0
    mov     ecx, second
    mov     edx, 30
    int 80H


    push first
    push second
    call _Stringgt
    mov esi, eax
    jmp DONE

_Stringgt:  
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    push edx
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]
    cld
    xor ecx, ecx
    LOOP:   
            mov al, [eax + ecx]
        cmp [ebx + ecx], al
        jb BIGGER
        ja SMALLER
        cmp al, LF
        je SAME
        inc ecx
        jmp LOOP
    BACK:
        pop ebp
        ret

    BIGGER:
        mov eax, bigprompt
                jmp BACK

    SMALLER:
        mov eax, smallprompt
                jmp BACK
    SAME:
        mov eax, sameprompt
            jmp BACK
DONE:   

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, esi
    mov edx, 30
    int 80H

    mov eax, 1              ; exit
    mov ebx, 0              
    int 80H
```

Comment: You `push edx` but forget to pop it, or equivalently, you forget to restore `esp` by doing `mov esp, ebp` at `BACK`.

Comment: Okay so now the line between `BACK:` and `pop ebp` I've put `mov esp, ebp` I do get output now, but it's going through all of my prompts instead of going to one and exiting. The output says `First is bigger Second is bigger They same`. Can you tell what might be causing that?

Comment: What's wrong with `edx`?

Comment: It's long enough to print all of your messages. If you're going to be calling this from C, you probably want zero-terminated strings anyway. Can you figure out how to calculate `edx` from a zero-terminated string?

Comment: Are my strings not zero terminated in this? And I thought I was calculating everything correctly, that's why I can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: No, your strings are not zero-terminated. Add `,0` to the end of 'em. Or IFF you use "back quotes" Nasm will recognize "\0", "\n" etc. Hint: `cmp byte [ecx + edx], 0` etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is too simple. you can use this function to get lengths of strings and determine which is larger.

```
;---------------------------------------------------------
;IN: takes zero terminated string address as parameter on stack
;OUT: String length in AX
;---------------------------------------------------------
str_length:

mov bp,sp
mov si, [bp+2]
mov al, [si]
mov bx,0

.loop:

cmp byte [si], 0
je .done
add si,1
add bx,1
jmp .loop


.done:

mov ax,bx
ret
;--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now you can do str_length two times and compare string lengths, such as

```
main:
mov ax,string1
push ax              ;give function parameter
call str_length       ;call the function
mov dx,ax             ;store string length in dx

mov ax,string2
push ax
call str_length      ; do this for string2

;now length of string1 is in dx and string2 is in ax we can compare them

cmp ax,dx
je equal
cmp ax,dx
ja greater
cmp ax,dx
jl less
```

Comment: Sorry I maybe should have been more specific, I mean which has the larger ASCII value. Like a is less than b

Comment: Can you type an example or help me fix my own code? It's not as easy for me at the moment. Also you said I need zero terminated strings, are my two strings in my code zero terminated?

Comment: your strings are not zero terminated add a zero with "," (comma) to make it zero terminated string such as:  foo: db "Bar" is not zero terminated and "foo: db "Bar",0 is zero terminated. If you can't understand email me at muazzam_ali@live.com thanks